# Cucumber + XCTest integration?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, xctest

We have an automation framework that uses Cucumber + Appium to test an iOS application.

Appium is fine, but one of its limitations is that we need to run every test from the beginning, which slows down development. XCTest seems to offer more breakpoint type flexibility, i.e. we can just re-run a small part of the test, as we already do with browser-based applications in Selenium.

XCTest seems easy to use and powerful, and we would like to start using it as soon as possible. Has anyone managed to integrate Cucumber with XCTest? We use Ruby for our framework and would like to keep using that also if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have recently integrated [Quick(a Swift BDD framework)](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) with the new XCTest and it all seems to be coming along fine.

As far as I know Cucumber don't have a Swift implementation yet so it is not possible to integrate Cucumber with XCTest.